# Visual C++ DLL Error C2039 trying to call Close() on a Windows Runtime type

Tags: visual-c++, dll, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

I'm trying to write a DLL to access the C++-only method [Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice.Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice) from a C# app. I seem to be able to access the class, but Visual Studio will not build if I try to use that one method. It is shown in the member list that comes up as you type, and there is no Intellisense error, just the build error.

```
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth;

__declspec(dllexport) void CloseBleDeviceUnmanaged(BluetoothLEDevice^device)
{
    if (device->ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus::Connected) //no complaints for a property
    {
        device->GetDeviceSelector(); //no complaints for a method either
        device->Close(); //Error C2039 | 'Close': is not a member of 'Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice'
    }

    return;
}
```

How do I get this to at least build?

(edit: removed extraneous syntax problem as per Nico Zhu - MSFT's answer)

Comment: I don't get the error. What version of Windows 10 does your project target? In the project's property pages, in the General node, what does Target Platform Version and Target Platform Min. Version have?

Comment: For the benefit of others, also see [Visual C++ DLL Error C2039 on single class method from Windows Universal API Contracts](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d95e9d9-f475-4c8e-afdd-2c674b541998/visual-c-dll-error-c2039-on-single-class-method-from-windows-universal-api-contracts?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: The error message is accurate, the Close() function is provided by the IClosable interface.  Using the ^ hat on WinRT type references is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do any of this to call `Close` from C# -- just put it in a `using(...)` block and it will dispose (close) the object for you automatically. If the lifetime of the objection doesn't lend itself well to a `using` block, you can simply call `IDisposabe.Dispose()` on it directly.

For the compiler error, this is [documented in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.IClosable) since you should never call `Close` from C++/CX:

> `Close` methods aren't callable through Visual C++ component extensions (C++/CX) on Windows Runtime class instances where the class implemented `IClosable`. Instead, Visual C++ component extensions (C++/CX) code for runtime classes should call the destructor or set the last reference to null.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure I do need to call `Close`. If you read the documentation for the class, `Close` "may close the connection", whereas `Dispose` only deals with "resources". Experimentally, I've verified that `Dispose` does not do what I want.

`Close` is specifically documented, so it must be usable somehow. How do you access the class (i.e. the Windows namespace) without C++/CX? I'm only using CX because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698949/how-to-access-namespace-windows).

Comment: The `Close` method **is** the `Dispose` method -- it is how the `IClosable` interface is projected into C# (just like `HSTRING` is projected as `System.String` and you never have to call any of the underlying Win32 `WindowsFooString` methods). C++/CX is only one of three ways to access WinRT from C++, but that's a red herring here.

Comment: So there's precisely *zero* chance that the C++ `Close` interacts with the Bluetooth drivers any differently than the C# `Dispose`?

Comment: As you have discovered, you can't actually call `Close` in C++/CX, so there is no equivalence. If you have reason to believe that it's not working (eg a minimal test that shows broken behavior) please let us know as it would be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of `CloseBleDeviceUnmanaged` method is `Value Type` in your case. When you pass a parameter to the method. The parameter will generate a copy. And the original parameter has not been changed. Please pass the 
reference type parameter like the follow.

```
void DevicesTool::CloseBleDeviceUnmanaged(Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::BluetoothLEDevice^device)
{
    if (device->ConnectionStatus == BluetoothConnectionStatus::Connected)
    {
        device->GetDeviceSelector();
        device->Close();
    }
}
```

As for the [`Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice#Methods) method, I have reproduced the issue in my side(target platform version 16299), and I have report this to related team. Please pay attention to the thread update.