# How to access Windows namespace from C++/WinRT component?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I have created a blank C++/WinRT component project via Visual Studio 2019.

I add this line to `Class.cpp`:

```cpp
    using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
```

Giving me this error:

```
Error   C2653   'Windows': is not a class or namespace name
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16698949/1438809), except that question was for C++/CX.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `using namespace winrt;` first

Comment: Oh wow, I spent hours on this :P  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entirety of the C++/WinRT projection resides in the `winrt` namespace. In other words, the Windows Runtime 'namespace' `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` is projected into `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls`.

To access that namespace, either use

```cpp
using namespace winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
```

or merge the `winrt` namespace into the global namespace first:

```cpp
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
```

Either one will cause you a fair amount of headaches once you move on to incorporate [WinUI](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) into your application. Due to types with the same name showing up under both the `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls` as well as `winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls` namespaces, the poor compiler gets lost in a sea of ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, that did it :)